# UITableViewCells aren't reloading when image is set

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, imageview

I have a UITableView and I am using Haneke to download images to display. When it finishes download, the cells don't reload. The images only show up upon scroll.

Here is my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("businessCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BusinessTableViewCell
    let business = self.businessObjects[indexPath.row]
    let photoReference = business.businessPhotoReference

    googlePlacesClient.getImageFromPhotoReference(photoReference) { (key) -> Void in

        self.cache.fetch(key: key).onSuccess { image in
            cell.businessBackgroundImage.hnk_setImage(image, key: photoReference)
            cell.businessBackgroundImage.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You probably need to reload the table view somewhere. `self.tableView.reloadData()` or something. Don't do this in `cellForRow:` though as you'll fire it lots of times.

Comment: You probably need to dispatch the `hnk_setImage` on the main queue